# Releasing for Windows Phone 7 only (not WP8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a game which I have developed for Windows Phone 7 using XNA 4 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. I submitted the app to the Windows Phone Store but failed certification because:

> 5.1 Application Reliability
>
> 5.1.1:
>
> The application fails to run on all windows 8 devices and displays a
> blank screen.

I would love to fix this, but I don't have a Windows 8 PC, and from what I can tell, you must be running on a Windows 8 PC to develop for Windows Phone 8 (see: [Windows Phone 8 SDK Requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)).

So, I was wondering if I can limit my app to *only* Windows Phone 7. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted the powers that be and explain that it's a Win7 only app?

Comment: @CL4PTR4P: I am opening a support ticket with them, but imagine it will be a while to hear a response. Have you heard of MS allowing apps to pass even though they don't run on WP8 by contacting them directly?

I imagine this is something that would need to be configured in the APP Manifest or something; not through MS directly. Figured someone here might have gone through this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Nokia's Remote Device Access service, which allows you to run your app on real Nokia hardware remotely. You cannot debug with it, but I was able to fix my bug by making small changes, testing on device, make another change, redeploy, and so on, until I found the cause of the bug.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/

Here is the repsonse I got from Microsoft, for anyone else interested in what their current stance is:

> I reviewed your case and you mention that your app failed
>   certification due to the app failing to launch on a Windows Phone 8
>   device. You also mention that you are unable to debug this as you do
>   not have a Windows 8 PC and would like the app to be released for
>   Windows Phone 7 devices only.
>
> All apps are released for Windows Phone 8 devices as they are setup to
>   be backwards compatible with Windows Phone 7 apps, this cannot be
>   opted out of. The link below provides additional information regarding
>   the Windows Phone 8 platform being backwards compatible.
>
> http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/01/15/app-submission-tips-for-windows-phone-7-and-windows-phone-8.aspx
>
> Since you do not have a Windows 8 PC to run the emulator you may want
>   to look at releasing your app as a beta and testing it on a Windows 8
>   Phone. This should allow you to replicate the issue the testers are
>   seeing. Additional information regarding beta testing can be found in
>   the link below.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx
>
> Please let me know if you have any additional concerns or questions as
>   I'd be happy to assist.

Comment: The bug itself was caused by setting PreferMultiSampling = true.

Answer (score 1):

You can not submit an application that only runs on pre-WP8 OSs (WP7 is no longer supported at all, though 7.5 is). Since running older apps is supported on WP8 there shouldn't be any issue, so I would open a ticket to try and get more information about what happened during certification that would have caused this app to not launch correctly on WP8.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this information on the Windows Phone Developer Forums:

> If you do not want your app visible for 8.0 devices, you can submit a support request and we will work with you 1:1 in providing some options. As of right now, there's no way for a developer to prevent WP8 distribution.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/2253f1d7-6e9f-4d34-8803-8b2bdf97061f/wp7-app-for-wp8

Comment: ...but this option should only be used if a developer has exhausted all other possibilities first (ie. an unfixable bug). If you want to debug the issue on a WP8 device, you could try [Nokia's Remote Device Access](https://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/Instructions_for_RDA_usage.xhtml) programme. Sign up as a Nokia developer (free) and you can access the programme.

Answer (score 0):

The option presented by Goose seems to no longer be available (as per a recent discussion I had with a MS support rep). Apps can no longer be excluded from WP 8.x compatibility.

There are other [valid reasons](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110711-dev-center-store/suggestions/3844619-allow-to-define-individual-pricing-for-each-xap-fi) for wanting an app to be for WP7 only, so it is frustrating that there seem to be no current solutions.

Comment: @dcastro My bad, I think I mistakenly commented on this.